# Nginx: что значит ^~в блоке location

Tags: nginx

```
Location ^~ /images/ {...}
```

Как понимать такую конструкцию, когда используется?

Comment: https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути сами символы `^~` можно перевести как "*не* регулярное выражение".

А реальное применение этому способу сопоставления адресов заключается в том, что такое сопоставление будет иметь бо́льший приоритет чем сопоставления по регулярному адресу.

Предположим, что мы хотим, чтобы все файлы сайта с расширением `.jpg` максимально кэшировались в браузере. Имеем сопоставление по регулярному выражению:

```
location ~ \.jpg$ {
   expires max;
}
```

Всё работает и файлы `.jpg` отправляются с соответствующими заголовками `Cache-Control`/`Expires`.

Через некоторое время, мы решили, что любые файлы в отдельно взятой папке `/images/foo/`, включая `.jpg` изображения *не* должны кэшироваться браузером вовсе.

Мы не можем использовать сопоставление по обычному префиксу. Это не сработает:

```
location /images/foo/ {
    expires -1;
}
```

Не сработает именно потому что в NGINX, сопоставления этого вида (обычные, по префиксу), имеют меньший приоритет, чем с регулярными выражениями.

С другой стороны сопоставление следующего формата даст желаемый результат:

```
location ^~ /images/foo/ {
   expires -1;
}
```

Таким образом `^~` это префиксное сопоставление адресов в NGINX конфигурации, имеющее приоритет над сопоставлениями по регулярному выражению.